# Есть ли в c++ библиотека, позволяющая работать с символьными выражениями?

Tags: c++, библиотеки, sympy

Хочется ввести строку "x**2 - 2*x + 1" и чтобы библиотека сделала что то волшебное, благодаря чему мы смогли бы посчитать ее значение в точке, подставив туда число.

На питоне есть sympy. Например, с sympy можно считать строку с помощью parse_expr, подставлять значения в функцию с помощью subs, решать уравнения и тп. Есть ли такой на плюсах?

Comment: Стандартного ничего такого нет.

Comment: sympy - это не про посчитать, а про символьные производные и т.п. Вам точно именно считать значение по формуле?

Comment: Если вводить строку, то понадобится динамический интерпретатор для выражений. По сути тот же самый python (который можно использовать из C++), так что смысл теряется. Хотя такое бывает, например [symengine](https://github.com/symengine/symengine) Ну а для различных математических манипуляций над фиксированными выражениями [полно библиотек](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/?view=category_math)

Comment: Если цель - просто посчитать выражение в какой-то точке, то это довольно просто. Тогда нужен синтаксический анализатор, который разбирает выражение. Писать его заново не обязательно, есть масса вариантов. В книге Шилдта, например, приведён код такого анализатора и его разбор.

Comment: Если нужно не просто посчитать выражение в одной точке, а быстро посчитать его много раз, то к синтаксическому анализатору нужно добавить некое подобие бэкенда компилятора, которое будет сохранять разобранное выражение в каком-то быстро вычислимом виде. Тут тоже возможны разные варианты вплоть до JIT-компиляции в машинный код. Если же нужны символьные операции над выражениями - дифференцирование, например, интегрирование, или символьное (не приблизительное) решение уравнений, то это уже другая задача. Тут надо подключать что-то серьёзное- питон, например